# Retrieving live value from range input to use in another function

Tags: javascript, input, return, range, global-variables

I know this is something really simple but I'm having trouble understanding how to return a live value from a range input slider and how to use that value in another function.

HTML

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
<div class="value">0</div>
```

JS

```
var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

var rangeValue = function(){
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var target = document.querySelector('.value');
  target.innerHTML = newValue;
  return newValue; 
}

function test(){
  console.log (newValue);
}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

I have been trying to retrieve the value with both global variables and return but keep running into problems. I would appreciate if anyone could explain how this can be done using both methods.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of "problems", can you post what results you are getting and what the expected results should be?

Comment: Your code works fine... What you mean by `running into problems`

Comment: I am not seeing any values from  'newValue' appear in the console

Comment: @NewbCake Of course not, you don't call the `test()` function anywhere. And your `return newValue;` is useless since there is nothing that can make use of it as it is the listeners callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

var rangeValue = function(){
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var target = document.querySelector('.value');
  target.innerHTML = newValue;
  test(newValue); 
}

function test(newValue){
  console.log (newValue);
}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

Test here: https://jsfiddle.net/k05qm2v5/

Also, using `querySelector('input[type="range"]')` is not the best idea.
You should give it a name or ID and get it like:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('miRange');
```

HTML:

```
<input id="myRange" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
<div class="value">0</div>
```

Comment: Ah okay that works. So you are calling the "test' function which that value is going to be used inside the first function? What happens if the value was going to be used in other functions? is there no need to use return or make a global variable?

Comment: Then just declare a variable at the top of the file, lets say var `globalVariable = null;` Then inside the rangeValue function you just put `globalVariable = newVarible;`

Comment: Keep in mind [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) says: **Do NOT** create global variables unless you intend to. Your global variables (or functions) can overwrite window variables (or functions).
Any function, including the window object, can overwrite your global variables and functions.

Comment: So what I am doing wrong in something like this – https://codepen.io/NewbCake/pen/rvYoay?editors=1011

Comment: You have one extra ")" here: `$("#fontSize").css({'font-size': newValue + 'px'});` after newValue